# awk multiple line script value redirection to file

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to make a list of al the files inside the location and its corresponding cvs version [which i will be going to compare to the latest version of git]. What i want to achieve is corresponding to each file path its version gets displayed for which i hv wrote a awk command, but the output of awk appends to the new line instead of that i want the output to be appended after the file path trailing with space. Please help

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in $(find /user4/c1upg1/ramesh/webapp_current/ -name \*.*);

do
echo $file >> namelist.log

awk '{
     if($2 == "$Id:")
        {
         print $3 $4
        }
      else if ($1 == "//$Id:")
        {
           print $2 $3
        }
     }' $file | tee -a namelist.log

done
```

Comment: Instead of `echo $file >> namelist.log` say `echo -n "$file " >> namelist.log`

Comment: thanks devnull for the quick suggestion, however i am not able to put the space between the two values, trying to figure it out [echo ' ' >> namelist.log puts the newline i am not sure why]

Comment: Read the previous comment _carefully_.  It said `echo -n`, not `echo`.

Comment: ok, working now thanks for the tip devnull [echo -n " " >> namelist.log]

Answer (score 0):

Scratch the echo command and print the file name by awk.

```
awk '{
     if($2 == "$Id:")
        {
         print FILENAME " " $3 " " $4
        }
      else if ($1 == "//$Id:")
        {
           print FILENAME " " $2 " " $3
        }
     }' $file | tee -a namelist.log

done
```